# (NSString *) it's in pascal a pointer or a NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delphi, nsstring, firemonkey

I have a doubt, on this function :

```
- (instancetype)initWithCenter:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)center
                            radius:(CLLocationDistance)radius
                        identifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

In pascal, does the `identifier:(NSString *)identifier` must be converted as **Pointer** or **NSString** ?

in the delphi source code, this function is converted like this :

```
function initWithCenter(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D; radius: CLLocationDistance; identifier: NSSTRING): Pointer; cdecl;
```

however when i use it i have an **AV under ios 10 (but it's work on ios 9)** :(

If i replace NSString by Pointer then it's work on IOS 10 but i don't understand why ...

**NOTE**: it's very strange because in delphi every `(NSString *)` are translated as `NSString` and it's work fine EXCEPT for `CLRegion.initCircularRegionWithCenter` (under ios10/64bit) and i really want to know why. https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15717 and http://delphiworlds.com/2016/07/region-monitoring-background-ios/

Comment: I don't have an iOS 9 device any more, however it was not working on iOS 9 (64 bit) for me, which is why I had to change it. Also pretty sure it was iOS 9.3, since I had the problem in July 2016, and 9.3 was released in March 2016

Comment: hmm so maybe it's connected to the compiler? i m under 32 bit me, not 64 bit

Comment: yes it's connected to the compiler (64 bit) see the answer of horacio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an Objective-C bridge problem, it is working fine for 32-bit support, the header translation of **CLRegion** is correct. The problem is that the bridge is not correctly working for 64-bit support, the Objective-C Runtime ABI is different for 32-bit and 64-bit supports. For purposes of clarification, the correct usage is **NSString** :), the bridge will take care of extract the handle (the pointer to the object created by the Objective-C Runtime) for you, it is the info which is passed to the Objective-C Runtime, in the current design, the handle extraction is done by:

```
Handle := (DelphiObject as ILocalObject).GetObjectID
```

or calling the below function from **Macapi.Helpers.pas**:

```
function NSObjectToID(const AObject: NSObject): Pointer;
```

The suggestion from Dave Nottage works because you are now bypassing the work of the bridge of extracting the handle and are passing it directly. It is exactly the point where the bridge is failing at its job. We don't need to go to low-level **Pointer** type here, for our bridge, the Delphi equivalent to Objective-C's **NSString *** is the **NSString** interface.

For more details, please see (https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15717). Thank you :)

Comment: Glad you liked, @Jack :D

Comment: Thank you for the tip, @DalijaPrasnikar

Comment: Thanks, @HorácioFilho

Comment: @DaveNottage Glad you liked :)